# Angularjs slider inconsistent pointer labels

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using the [angularjs-slider](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider) and it has an issue of the pointerLabels as not consistent. Sometimes it's in the right position, sometimes stayed at the left. Here are my screenshots:

**CORRECT POSITION**
[image]

**WRONG POSITION**
[image]

Maybe someone has experienced it or has solution for it. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you populating the ng-model value asynchronously? May need to manually call `$apply`. Or try pointing your ng-model values to object properties, vs plain integers.

Comment: I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by populating the ng-model value asynchronously? Currently the ng-model that used by the textbox and slider is pointing to object rather than a integer variable.